# How to generate auto complete code for using with ajax?

Tags: ajax

I want to create a user id for login. It should have a 10 digit.

10 digit number- (First 2 alphabets representing state another two represent district and last two digit as same as last digit of pin code and the remaining 4 digit as per the roll number)

Eg: sampel User id : TACO08001

there is 2 drop down box, one is select state and other is select district,

Example shows TA , if we select Tamil Nadu, in the userid autocomplete box generate TA, and then if we select Coimbatore, in the userid autocomplete box generate CO and also  the next 2 digit shows of particular district pincode of last digit, and last 4 digit  generate a roll number like start with 0001, if the second user create a form then it will 0002 ,0003...so on

How to create a autocomplete code for using ajax ?

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select id="state" name="group_id" class="form-control">
                <option value="9999">None</option>
                            <option value="1">Kerala</option>
                            <option value="2">Tamil Nadu</option>
                            <option value="3">Karnataka</option>
                            <option value="4">Gujarat</option>
                            <option value="5">Delhi</option>
                            <option value="6">Goa</option>
                            <option value="7">Assam</option>
                            <option value="8">Punjab</option>
                            <option value="9">Rajasthan</option>
                          </select> 
              <span class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select id="district" name="group_id" class="form-control">
                <option value="9999">None</option>
                            <option value="2">Coimbatore</option>
                        <option value="3">Banglore</option>
                        <option value="4">Kochi</option>
                        <option value="5">Hyderabad</option>
                        <option value="6">Chennai</option>
                        <option value="7">Ernakulam</option>
                        <option value="8">Pune</option>
                        <option value="9">Noida</option>
        </select>
              <span class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you want someone else to write code for you? Haven't you tried yourself?

Comment: share your code for better undestanding

Comment: ok i will try wait for some time

Comment: i will try using your code but its not work and i not understand

Comment: @Bhargav  There is 2 drop down box,  1st is for select State, 2nd is for select  district. And next is a autocomplete box. If I select a state in the dropdown  while autocomplete value generate the first two characters, next I select a district autocomplete value generate first 2 charaters of district

Comment: and where is roll no and pincode

Comment: so i have where to get pincode and roll no its from dropdown or from database ,pincode and roll_no in which element so i use for generate uid